# can I use a msp file in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I am trying to create a setup that installs other programs on a desktop.
one of these files is a msp file and i run it like a normal exe file.
I have tried to open it like you would an msi file with no possitive result.
Can anyone help?[this is how i currently try to run it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgV4r.png)

[this is the error i receive its in dutch but a rough translation is "cannot open this installation package. contact the provider of the file or check if it is a valid windows installer package.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5N35s.png)

Comment: *"i run it like a normal exe file or msi"* and *"I have tried to open it like you would an msi file with no possitive result"* seem to contradict one another. - Or does the first refer to some manual action, while the latter to some (Inno Setup) script? If the latter, show us the script that you have tried.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I have added an image hope it will help.

Comment: Please do not post code as an image. Post it as a text.

Comment: Did you try `msiexec` on a command-line first?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl how do you mean?

Comment: OK, so maybe you should first go to [su] and ask a genefic question how to install that .msp from a command-line (post a link here, when you do). And once you get an answer to that, you can come here asking how to implement that in Inno Setup (though I assume that an answer to that will be trivial).

Comment: `msiexec.exe \i path\to\your\file.msp` Then see if you get any errors. If you don't get any errors then is most likely some missing quote within the `Parameters` section in inno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it took a while , but i fixed the bug.
I used the msp file as an msi file.
I used the wrong parameter you need to use /p instead of /i